# Selecting Inner HTML of child element in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use JQUERY to obtain the value of a child node of an element that is clicked on. I have been researching this and haven't found an answer that seems to work. I am trying to obtain the text that says 'this is what i want'

My HTML looks similar to this

```
<div class="a">
    <article class="b">
        <section class="c">
            <div class="d">
                <a class="e" href="https://"><img src="https:/"></a> 
                    <div class="f"><div class="g">
                        <a href="https:" >this is what i want</a>
```

My JQUERY looks similar to this

```
 $("div").click(function(){

var a = jQuery(this).children('.g > a').html;
      console.log(a);
});
```

I've also tried

```
    $("div").click(function(){

var a = jQuery(this).find('.g > a').html;
      console.log(a);
});
```

Comment: there is no `a` that is a direct child of `.f` so `.f > a` wont work. You could do `.g > a` or just `.f a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe `>` selector is only for direct children, which as isn't a direct child. And you're missing the `.html()` in your second example.

```js
$("div.a").click(function(){
  var a = jQuery(this).find('.f a').html();
  console.log(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
    <article class="b">
        <section class="c">
            <div class="d">
                <a class="e" href="https://"><img src="https:/"></a> 
                    <div class="f"><div class="g">
                        <a href="https:" >this is what i want</a>
```

Comment: when you run the code, it returns 4 values: `undefined, undefined, "this is what I want", "this is what I want"`. Why? Because there are 4 `div`s and the click event is attached to all of them

Comment: Thanks. I actually made a typo it was .g > a. I tried your suggestion and that doesn't work either in my actual code but it works in my example html. I will have to go back an debug. Thank you.

Comment: @nfnneil this is why I told OP to specify which element to attach the eventListener to

Comment: Silly mistake... the issue was I didnt have () after html.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be more specific with the `div` that is being clicked by calling it by className.

```js
$(".a").click(function(e){
  var a = $(this).find(".f").children("a");
  console.log($(a).text());
});
```

```css
.a{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
    <article class="b">
        <section class="c">
            <div class="d">
                <a class="e" href="https://"><img src="https:/"></a> 
                <div class="f"><div class="g"></div>
                        <a href="https:" >this is what i want</a>
                        </div>
              </div>
              </section>
              </article>
              </div><!--end a-->
```

Comment: I have tried that and It still doesn't work. It gets a bit challenging because there is a lot of nested HTML on that page. I do believe that particular div is reflected in THIS though from other tests.